# Can't modify my script for multiplayer quiz? Roblox Studio

Tags: lua, roblox, roblox-studio

I am a small roblox developper and I ran into a problem.
Right now, I made a localScript for a quiz game that asks question from data and the user must answer the question in a certain amount of time (Like shown on the image)

[Result of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYp19.png)

The problem I am trying to solve is that for now, the game only works for the individual that starts de quiz, not the others

But I have no idea how to modify my script so that everyone has the same questions at the same time.

I tried to learn the RemoteEvent strategy but it never worked after 5 hours of trying again and again

Here is the code of the Quiz right now

```
local trivialevel1 = {
    { --Math
        question = "What is the mathematical constant π (pi) approximately equal to?",
        answers = {"2.718","3.142","1.618","0.577"},
        correctanswer = 2,
        category = "Math"
    },
    {
        question = "What is the result of multiplying any number by zero?",
        answers = {"1","The number itself","Zero","Infinity"},
        correctanswer = 3,
        category = "Math"
    },
    {
        question = "What is the term for a polygon with five sides?",
        answers = {"Hexagon","Octagon","Pentagon","Heptagon"},
        correctanswer = 3,
        category = "Math"
    },
    {
        question = "What is the value of the square root of 144?",
        answers = {"144","16","9","12"},
        correctanswer = 4,
        category = "Math"
    },
    {
        question = "What is the sum of all angles in a triangle?",
        answers = {"270","180","360","90"},
        correctanswer = 2,
        category = "Math"
    },
    {
        question = "If a number is divisible by 2 and 3, what other number is it also divisible by?",
        answers = {"4","8","6","5"},
        correctanswer = 3,
        category = "Math"
    },
    { --Sports
        question = "Which country won the most recent FIFA World Cup in 2022?",
        answers = {"Brazil","Germany","France","Argentina"},
        correctanswer = 4,
        category = "Sports"
    },
    { 
        question = "Which sport is associated with the term 'slam dunk'?",
        answers = {"Soccer","Tennis","Baseball","Basketball"},
        correctanswer = 4,
        category = "Sports"
    },
    { 
        question = "In baseball, how many strikes constitute a strikeout for a batter?",
        answers = {"4","2","3","1"},
        correctanswer = 3,
        category = "Sports"
    },
    { --Geography
        question = "What is the world's largest ocean?",
        answers = {"Atlantic Ocean","Idian Ocean","Artic Ocean","Pacific Ocean"},
        correctanswer = 4,
        category = "Geography"
    },
    { 
        question = "What is the capital city of Japan?",
        answers = {"Beijing","Seoul","Tokyo","Bangkok"},
        correctanswer = 3,
        category = "Geography"
    },
    { 
        question = "What is the largest country in Africa by land area?",
        answers = {"Nigeria","Egypt","South Africa","Algeria"},
        correctanswer = 4,
        category = "Geography"
    }
    
}

local trivialevel2 = {
    { --Math
        question = "Which of the following is the smallest prime number?",
        answers = {"3","2","1","4"},
        correctanswer = 2,
        category = "Math"
    },
    {
        question = "In the equation E=mc², what does the 'c' represent?",
        answers = {"Speed of light", "Planck constant","Gravitational constant","Electric charge"},
        correctanswer = 1,
        category = "Math"
    },
    { --Sports
        question = "Which athelete is often referred to as The Fastest Man on Earth?",
        answers = {"Michael Phelps","Usain Bolt","LeBron James","Cristiano Ronaldo"},
        correctanswer = 2,
        category = "Sports"
    },
    { 
        question = "Which Winter Olympic sport involves atheletes sliding down a frozen track on a sled?",
        answers = {"Ice hockey","Curling","Ski jumping","Skeleton"},
        correctanswer = 4,
        category = "Sports"
    },
    { 
        question = "In American football, how many points is a safety worth? ",
        answers = {"2","3","6","1"},
        correctanswer = 1,
        category = "Sports"
    },
    { 
        question = "Which tennis player has won the most Wimbledon titles in the men's singles category?",
        answers = {"Andre Agassi","Rafael Nadal","Roger Federer","Novak Djokovic"},
        correctanswer = 3,
        category = "Sports"
    },
    { --Geography
        question = "Which continent is home to the Sahara Desert, the largest hot desert in the world?",
        answers = {"South America","Africa","Asia","Australia"},
        correctanswer = 2,
        category = "Geography"
    },
    { 
        question = "Which river is the longest in the world?",
        answers = {"Nile","Amazon","Yangtze","Mississippi"},
        correctanswer = 1,
        category = "Geography"
    },
    { 
        question = "Which European country is known as the 'Land of Fire and Ice' due to its volcanic activity and glaciers?",
        answers = {"Sweden","Finland","Iceland","Norway"},
        correctanswer = 3,
        category = "Geography"
    },
    { --Food
        question = "Which Italian pasta is shaped like small rice grains?",
        answers = {"Penne","Fusilli","Orzo","Linguine"},
        correctanswer = 3,
        category = "Food"
    },
}

local trivialevel3 = {
    { --Math
        question = "Which famous mathematician is known for his work on the theory of relativity?",
        answers = {"Isaac Newton","Galileo Galilei","Albert Einstein","Archimedes"},
        correctanswer = 3,
        category = "Math"
    },
    {  --Sports
        question = "What is the national sport of Japan?",
        answers = {"Sumo wrestling","Judo","Karate","Kendo"},
        correctanswer = 1,
        category = "Sports"
    },
    { 
        question = "Which gold major is held at Augusta National Golf Club?",
        answers = {"The Open Championship","The PGA Championship","The Masters Tournament","The U.S Open"},
        correctanswer = 3,
        category = "Sports"
    },
    { 
        question = "Which country is known for dominating the sport of cricket and is considered a cricket powerhouse?",
        answers = {"England","Australia","South Africa","India"},
        correctanswer = 4,
        category = "Sports"
    },
    { --Geography
        question = "The Great Barrier Reef, one of the world's most famous coral reef systems, is located off the coast of which country?",
        answers = {"Brazil","Australia","Indonesia","Mexico"},
        correctanswer = 2,
        category = "Geography"
    },
    { 
        question = "Which mountain range stretches across seven countries in South America?",
        answers = {"Rocky Mountains","Andes","Alps","Himalayas"},
        correctanswer = 2,
        category = "Geography"
    },
    { 
        question = "Which famous canal connects the Mediterranean Sea to the Red Sea?",
        answers = {"Suez Canal","Panama Canal","Kiel Canal","Corinth Canal"},
        correctanswer = 1,
        category = "Geography"
    },
    { 
        question = "What is the smallest independent country in the world, both in terms of area and population?",
        answers = {"Monaco","Vatican City","Liechtenstein","San Marino"},
        correctanswer = 2,
        category = "Geography"
    },
}



local question = script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Quiz.Frame.Question
local answer1 = script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Quiz.Frame.Answer1
local answer2 = script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Quiz.Frame.Answer2
local answer3 = script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Quiz.Frame.Answer3
local answer4 = script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Quiz.Frame.Answer4
local category = script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Quiz.Frame.Category
local currentquestionindex = 1
local selectedIndex = 0
local buttons = {answer1,answer2,answer3,answer4}

local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer

 --TIMER
local timer = script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Quiz.Frame.Timer
local countdownDuration = 10
local currentCountdown = countdownDuration
local isCounting = false


local function updateTimer()
    while isCounting and currentCountdown > 0 do
        timer.Text = tostring(currentCountdown)
        wait(1)
        currentCountdown = currentCountdown - 1
    end

    timer.Text = "Time's up!"
end

local function startCountdown()
    isCounting = true
    currentCountdown = countdownDuration
    updateTimer()
end

local function stopCountdown()
    isCounting = false
end



local function shuffle(array)
    local n = #array
    for i = n, 2, -1 do
        local j = math.random(i)
        array[i], array[j] = array[j], array[i]
    end
end

local function displayQuestionlevel1(index)
    local questionData = trivialevel1[index]
    question.Text = questionData.question
end

local function displayQuestionlevel2(index)
    local questionData = trivialevel2[index]
    question.Text = questionData.question
end

local function displayQuestionlevel3(index)
    local questionData = trivialevel3[index]
    question.Text = questionData.question
end

local function displayAnswerslevel1(index)
    local answersdata = trivialevel1[index]
    answer1.Text = answersdata.answers[1]
    answer2.Text = answersdata.answers[2]
    answer3.Text = answersdata.answers[3]
    answer4.Text = answersdata.answers[4]
end

local function displayAnswerslevel2(index)
    local answersdata = trivialevel2[index]
    answer1.Text = answersdata.answers[1]
    answer2.Text = answersdata.answers[2]
    answer3.Text = answersdata.answers[3]
    answer4.Text = answersdata.answers[4]
end

local function displayAnswerslevel3(index)
    local answersdata = trivialevel3[index]
    answer1.Text = answersdata.answers[1]
    answer2.Text = answersdata.answers[2]
    answer3.Text = answersdata.answers[3]
    answer4.Text = answersdata.answers[4]
end

local function displayCategorylevel1(index)
    local categorydata = trivialevel1[index]
    category.Text = categorydata.category
end

local function displayCategorylevel2(index)
    local categorydata = trivialevel2[index]
    category.Text = categorydata.category
end

local function displayCategorylevel3(index)
    local categorydata = trivialevel3[index]
    category.Text = categorydata.category
end

local function addCoins(amount)
    player:WaitForChild("leaderstats"):WaitForChild("Coins").Value = player.leaderstats.Coins.Value + amount
end

script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Quiz.bouton.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    
    local error1 = script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Quiz.Frame.Error1
    local error2 = script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Quiz.Frame.Error2
    local error3 = script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Quiz.Frame.Error3
    
    error1.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(255, 255, 255)
    error2.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(255, 255, 255)
    error3.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(255, 255, 255)
    
    script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Quiz.Frame.Visible = true
    
    local questionsdone = 0
    
    local errorCount = 0
    
    
    while(questionsdone < 7) do
        script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Quiz.Frame.Answer1.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(255,122,69)
        script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Quiz.Frame.Answer2.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(255,122,69)
        script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Quiz.Frame.Answer3.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(255,122,69)
        script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Quiz.Frame.Answer4.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(255,122,69)
        shuffle(trivialevel1)
        displayQuestionlevel1(currentquestionindex)
        displayAnswerslevel1(currentquestionindex)
        displayCategorylevel1(currentquestionindex)
        
        startCountdown()
        
        if selectedIndex == trivialevel1[currentquestionindex].correctanswer then
            buttons[selectedIndex].BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(35, 255, 19)
            addCoins(10)
        else
            buttons[trivialevel1[currentquestionindex].correctanswer].BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(35, 255, 19)
            buttons[selectedIndex].BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(255,0,0)
            
            errorCount = errorCount + 1
            if errorCount == 1 then
                error1.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(255, 0, 0)  -- Rouge
            elseif errorCount == 2 then
                error2.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(255, 0, 0) -- Rouge
            elseif errorCount == 3 then
                error3.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(255, 0, 0)  -- Rouge
                -- Code pour le personnage qui meurt ici (ajoutez votre propre logique)
                game.Players.LocalPlayer.Character:BreakJoints()
            end
        end
        
        wait(5)
        
        questionsdone = questionsdone + 1
    end
    
    while(questionsdone < 14) do
        script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Quiz.Frame.Answer1.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(255,122,69)
        script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Quiz.Frame.Answer2.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(255,122,69)
        script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Quiz.Frame.Answer3.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(255,122,69)
        script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Quiz.Frame.Answer4.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(255,122,69)
        shuffle(trivialevel2)
        displayQuestionlevel2(currentquestionindex)
        displayAnswerslevel2(currentquestionindex)
        displayCategorylevel2(currentquestionindex)
        
        startCountdown()

        if selectedIndex == trivialevel2[currentquestionindex].correctanswer then
            buttons[selectedIndex].BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(35, 255, 19)
            addCoins(10)
        else
            buttons[trivialevel2[currentquestionindex].correctanswer].BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(35, 255, 19)
            buttons[selectedIndex].BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(255,0,0)
            
            errorCount = errorCount + 1
            if errorCount == 1 then
                error1.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(255, 0, 0)  -- Rouge
            elseif errorCount == 2 then
                error2.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(255, 0, 0) -- Rouge
            elseif errorCount == 3 then
                error3.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(255, 0, 0)  -- Rouge
                -- Code pour le personnage qui meurt ici (ajoutez votre propre logique)
                game.Players.LocalPlayer.Character:BreakJoints()
            end
        end
        
        wait(5)
        
        questionsdone = questionsdone + 1
    end
    
    while(nil) do
        script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Quiz.Frame.Answer1.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(255,122,69)
        script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Quiz.Frame.Answer2.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(255,122,69)
        script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Quiz.Frame.Answer3.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(255,122,69)
        script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Quiz.Frame.Answer4.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(255,122,69)
        shuffle(trivialevel3)
        displayQuestionlevel3(currentquestionindex)
        displayAnswerslevel3(currentquestionindex)
        displayCategorylevel3(currentquestionindex)
        
        startCountdown()

        if selectedIndex == trivialevel3[currentquestionindex].correctanswer then
            buttons[selectedIndex].BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(35, 255, 19)
            addCoins(10)
        else
            buttons[trivialevel3[currentquestionindex].correctanswer].BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(35, 255, 19)
            buttons[selectedIndex].BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(255,0,0)
            
            errorCount = errorCount + 1
            if errorCount == 1 then
                error1.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(255, 0, 0)  -- Rouge
            elseif errorCount == 2 then
                error2.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(255, 0, 0) -- Rouge
            elseif errorCount == 3 then
                error3.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(255, 0, 0)  -- Rouge
                -- Code pour le personnage qui meurt ici (ajoutez votre propre logique)
                game.Players.LocalPlayer.Character:BreakJoints()
            end
        end
        
        wait(5)

        questionsdone = questionsdone + 1
    end
    
    
end)

script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Quiz.Frame.Answer1.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    selectedIndex = 1
    script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Quiz.Frame.Answer1.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(143,68,39)
    script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Quiz.Frame.Answer1.Active = false
    script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Quiz.Frame.Answer2.Active = false
    script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Quiz.Frame.Answer3.Active = false
    script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Quiz.Frame.Answer4.Active = false
end)

script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Quiz.Frame.Answer2.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    selectedIndex = 2
    script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Quiz.Frame.Answer2.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(143,68,39)
    script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Quiz.Frame.Answer1.Active = false
    script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Quiz.Frame.Answer2.Active = false
    script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Quiz.Frame.Answer3.Active = false
    script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Quiz.Frame.Answer4.Active = false
end)

script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Quiz.Frame.Answer3.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    selectedIndex = 3
    script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Quiz.Frame.Answer3.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(143,68,39)
    script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Quiz.Frame.Answer1.Active = false
    script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Quiz.Frame.Answer2.Active = false
    script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Quiz.Frame.Answer3.Active = false
    script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Quiz.Frame.Answer4.Active = false
end)

script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Quiz.Frame.Answer4.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    selectedIndex = 4
    script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Quiz.Frame.Answer4.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(143,68,39)
    script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Quiz.Frame.Answer1.Active = false
    script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Quiz.Frame.Answer2.Active = false
    script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Quiz.Frame.Answer3.Active = false
    script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Quiz.Frame.Answer4.Active = false
end)
```

Thank you for any help you guys can give me :)

I am available to give you any other information needed to solve my problem